# UWP Screen Capture OR Recording

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I want Screen Recording in UWP. Or Screen capture so that I can move ahead with per moment collection and convert those total captures to a video.

Comment: [Coming soon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture).

Comment: Is there any way to publish at windows store, if i develop this in wpf

Comment: You can use the Desktop Bridge to publish WPF apps to the Windows Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Screen recording in UWP, you can see this similar thread:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dfa72a44-6888-41bd-a002-1253799027e4/uwpcscreen-capture-and-save-as-video?forum=wpdevelop

As @Rob's reply, general purpose screen recorders are not possible in UWP. You can use techniques such as what @Cole shared to capture your own app's screen . Please see the [RenderTargetBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap) Class.

As for developing this in wpf and publishing at windows store, you can create a wpf app then convert it to UWP, after that you can publish at windows store. See the [Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root) topic.

Answer (score 4):

In a recent update Screen Capture was added for Windows 1803 using the Windows.Graphics.Capture namespace. I have yet to get it to work since i'm also building an app that needs it, but at least it should be possible now. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture 
For the meantime I created a workaround using the Windows Game Bar. It activates by pressing "Windows + Alt + R" so i simulated that keyinput in UWP for starting and stopping the recording. It's a very dirty method for sure, but it's the only thing I came up with.

Comment: yeah good to know but it will only capture the single thing, means one program at a time....

Comment: @hmak.soft there is now support for recording a specific region as well.